# Variable time axis in (time-)charts

Tags: charts, data-analysis, anylogic, energy

I have built an energy flow simulation for factories in Anylogic. I would like to do a detailed analysis in the Anylogic model (not in Excel), looking at energy flows that I currently plot in a chart over the whole year at other levels of detail. For example, I would like to look at the energy profile of the same graph with a time axis that represents only one month, one week, or as the smallest unit, one day. Ideally, I can still change the time period after the simulation has run through.

My first approach was to simply create different graphs and link a parameter, e.g. the month, to the visibility of the graph.

However, the effort is very large, since I would have to create 365 diagrams just to be able to display each day.
Does anyone of you know a way to automate this chart creation or a way to make the x-axis of charts more flexible. Are there already solutions for this problem or does anyone know how this could work?

Best Christoph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to:

- have 1 time plot only (with no dataset at all initially)
- have a dataset that stores all your data (x values are days, y values your data for the day)
- use a function to create your own custom dataset `mySpecificDS` using `DataSet mySpecificDS = new DataSet(numberOfDays)` (see help to see how to code datasets directly) --> this should cover only the time period of interest from your full dataset that contains all days
- add your custom `mySpecificDS` to your chart using `plot.AddDataSet(mySpecificDS)`

You can remove old datasets from your plot as well using `plot.remove(mySpecificDS)` if you want to plot a new one.

Check the help for those functions for more info

Comment: Thanks Benjamin I will try to implement your solution, today :)

Comment: If it helped, please upvote the answer, helps others with similar problems find it easier in the future, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote

Comment: My functions looks like this:
specificDataset.setCapacity(monthCapacity);
specificDataset.fillFrom(datasetTEST); 
Help: https://anylogic.help/api/com/anylogic/engine/analysis/DataSet.html
2 problems:
1) DataSet: I can populate the spec. DataSet with data using a refresh button. However, I cannot populate the specific DataSet with the Data from June after the simulation is finished.

2)Plot: I haven't found a way to adjust the scale on the x-axis so that the plot shows only the month I want to see, i.e. June. After the simulation is completed, it's always in the last simulated month.

Comment: Always ask new questions in new issues, this also helps others with similar issues. See https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow

Comment: Ok, I think I got the point, I will do two issues regarding the DataSet and the Plot question, thanks.